# PouchDB data from a child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pouchdb

I suspect this can also be a normal React question, however I'm building a react-native app, and am pretty new to all of this, so hopefully I'm just not grasping a concept.

In my Home.js (my main screen component), I'm performing a replicate.from in my app, which pull data from my couchDB server into my app (a one-way sync) and create an index.  That code looks like this

```
this.remoteDB = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/cs-test");

this.localDB = new PouchDB("cs-test", { adapter: "asyncstorage" });
this.localDB.replicate
  .from(this.remoteDB, {
    live: true,
    retry: true
  })
  .then(function(localDb) {
    localDb
      .createIndex({
        index: {
          fields: ["type"],
          name: "type"
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

I then (just to be sure its working) query and dump out that data to the console using my index.

```
this.localDB
  .find({
    selector: {
      type: { $eq: "sessions" }
    }
  })
  .then(
    function(result) {
      console.log("HOME result");
      console.log(result);
    }.bind(this)
  )
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

this works perfectly.

My question is, in the render function of Home.js, I'm including 3 components that all will use the localDB data.  I was under the assumption that PouchDB's data was app-wide, but it seems that this.localDB is only accessible in Home.js (which makes sense as I type it because of the 'this').

Any idea how I can access the pouchDB data in my child components?

Comment: You could set the `result` in your `Home` component state with `setState` and then pass that state down as props to your child components.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get this to work in a test app. I do like the idea @alex-green has below, so I may give that a try as well just to keep the component clean.  Appreciate the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need access to your localDB from different components I'd recommend to move all DB-related stuff (getDoc, saveDoc, pullDocs etc) to one module and then import it where it is needed. Like this:

```
// pdb.js
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-react-native';
const localDB = new PouchDB(localDBname, {adapter: 'asyncstorage'});
const PDB = {};
PDB.getDoc = (docID)=> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
    localDB.get(docID)
    .then((result)=> {return resolve(result)})
    .catch((err)=> {
      if (err.status === 404) {
        // console.log(' ???????????? getDoc not found: ', docID)
        return resolve(null)
      } else {
        // console.log('[!!!!======>!!!!!!] getDoc err: ', err)
        return reject(err)
      }
    })
  })
}

PDB.saveDoc = (doc)=> {
...do stuff
}

module.exports = PDB;
```

and then import and use it in any component you need it:

```
//mycomponent.js
import PDB from './pdb';
...
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

componentDidMount() {
PDB.getDoc(docID)
.then((doc)=> {
 this.setState({name: doc.name})
})
}

render() {
 return (
...
```

Comment: Thank you for that idea, I'm going to try this out. I really like the idea of removing all of the database clutter from my main file.  I'll post back in a bit (I hope with good news) :)